# Ruby on Rails 3: Playing with Select on Input Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I created an input page with a textbox in every field, and it's working.

I changed one field in the select box with the following code:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :position %><br />
    <%= select_tag "position", options_for_select(%w{ mainpost bannerpost2 minipost1 minipost2 minipost3 }) %> 
</div>
```

When I edit my new post, I change the `select_tag` value into `bannerpost2`, and then I update my post, but the field of `position` doesn't change into `bannerpost2`.

---

Also, when I edit my post, the `f.select` doesn't change automatically into it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to use `f.select` instead of `select_tag`, because rails automatically append table name to each ids, f.select will be "post_position" if your table is "Posts", but select_tag will be just "position", so data won't get stored in db.
- For previous value saved in db, should pass it as an arg to options_for_select

In case, if your table name is "`Posts`", pass `@post.position`

```
f.select :position, 
   options_for_select(%w{ mainpost bannerpost2 minipost1 minipost2 minipost3 },
   @post.position)
```

Comment: is f.select syntax is the same as select_tag?

Comment: @mamatozay, yes, syntaxes are same